# How Data locality of locality level PROCESS_LOCAL works in Spark with dynamic allocation enabled

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-2.0

In case of dynamic allocation executors are removed after a certain idle time so there could be time when there are zero executor running.
So when a task is submitted at time when there is no executor running will there by any task with data locality as `PROCESS_LOCAL`? Because `PROCESS_LOCAL` means data is located inside a JVM, and currently no executors are UP.

Comment: As you explained yourself, with --master other than `local` it is impossible for the first task to be scheduled with `PROCESS_LOCAL` locality.

Comment: @mazaneicha so subsequent task only has chances of getting scheduled with PROCESS_LOCAL? And only when an executor is running and we have another task which has to be executed on data located inside the running executor , will be scheduled with PROCESS_LOCAL right?

Comment: AFAIK, generally yes, although there might be some exceptions - consider a situation where task is executed on data block that was **broadcasted** to every executor from the driver.

Comment: @mazaneicha Thanks!